# setAttribute("style", "overflow: hidden;") не работает

Tags: javascript

есть код

```js
var obj_div = document.getElementById('filter_knob_id_1');
obj_div.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid #CECECE;background:#ffffff;");
obj_div.setAttribute("style", "overflow: hidden;");
```

```html
<div id="filter_knob_id_1" name="scr_head" style="border:1px solid #CECECE;background:#ffffff;">
  <input type='checkbox' $sel_str onchange='document.filter_note.submit()' name='vendor_1' id='id_1_1'><label for='id_1_1' id='label_id_1_1'>Asus</label><br>
  <input type='checkbox' $sel_str onchange='document.filter_note.submit()' name='vendor_2' id='id_1_2'><label for='id_1_2' id='label_id_1_2'>MSI</label><br>
  <input type='checkbox' $sel_str onchange='document.filter_note.submit()' name='vendor_3' id='id_1_3'><label for='id_1_3' id='label_id_1_3'>GigaByte</label>

</div>
```

не могу понять, почему не работает obj_div.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid #CECECE;background:#ffffff;");  (при выполнении этого фрагмента javascript border принимает значение 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)) 
и  obj_div.setAttribute("style", "overflow: hidden;"); это тоже не выполняется..

Comment: все выполняется, как Вы и закодировали. Посмотрите в консоле

Comment: Каждый вызов `setAttribute` заменяет текущее значение на новое.

Comment: `elt.style.overflow = “hidden”;`

Comment: Запустил ваш код, посмотрел содержимое div — там написано `style="overflow: hidden;"`. То есть всё отлично работает и вопрос непонятен

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать один из следующих способов

```
// Устанавливает несколько стилей в одном выражении
elt.style.cssText = "color: blue; border: 1px solid black"; 

// Или
elt.setAttribute("style", "color:red; border: 1px solid blue;");
```

В вашем случае вы перезаписываете атрибут

Подробнее:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style